# Limits of fraction with trigonometric functions?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Find the limit of:

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{1 - 2\cos{x}}{\pi - 3x}$$

How could I cancel the denominator?

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Yep, differentiate both: numerator and denominator?

Comment: Exactly. Then, you will get $-3$ on bottom and $2\sin(x)$ on top, so evaluating that at $\frac{\pi}{3}$ should give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use l'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{1-2\cos(x)}{\pi-3x}=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{3}}\frac{2\sin(x)}{-3}=-\frac{2}{3}\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{3}}\sin(x)=-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $\cos$ at $\frac{\pi}{3}
 $ we get $$\frac{1}{3}\frac{1-2\cos\left(2\right)}{\frac{\pi}{3}-x}=-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sqrt{3}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{2}\right)}{x-\frac{\pi}{3}}\underset{x\rightarrow\pi/3}{\rightarrow}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Put $x = \frac{\pi}{3}+h$. Then the given limit is 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+h\right)}{-3h} &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{1 - \cos h + \sqrt{3}\sin h}{-3h} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {2\sin^2 \frac{h}{2}}{-3h} + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\sqrt{3}\frac{\sin h}{-3h} \\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{y\to A}\dfrac{\cos2A-\cos2y}{2A-2y}=-\lim_{y\to A}\dfrac{\sin(A-y)}{A-y}\cdot \lim_{y\to A}\sin(A+y)=-\sin(A+A)$$

Here $2A=\dfrac\pi3,2y=x$